# What is the new understanding that emerged about the death penalty that recently entered the Catechism?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, capital-punishment

What the heck does this sentence added to the Catechism mean?

> In addition, a new understanding has emerged of the significance of penal sanctions imposed by the state.

https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2018/08/02/180802a.html

What new understanding?  What significance?  What sanctions? Is this even a complete sentence?

Comment: Colloquially, in politics, a 'new understanding' generally means a change (usually a reversal) of policy.

Comment: I am just as confused as you are, and so do many people, illustrated by this long (but substantial) [blog article from *Thomistica*](https://thomistica.net/posts/2018/8/4/thomist-responses-to-pope-franciss-revision-of-ccc-2267) containing links to responses by prominent Catholic scholars like Ed Feser, Thomas Petri.  Especially pertinent are the 3 thoughts on the new language by Tony Montanaro in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

The strange thing about death penalty is that there is no uniformity across the nations on the crimes to which it is applicable, level of the court which is competent to award it, different authorities to whom appeal can be made, and the manner by which the convict is put to death in execution  of the  penalty. India, for instance, is a secular nation where death penalty is in vogue, but is to be awarded in  `rarest of the rare` ' cases. The convict is given a fair trail, and is mandated to appeal to the Apex Court and then to seek mercy from the President . It takes years together to complete the legal process and to execute the convict, so that nothing is left to speculation that he/she had not been given a fair chance to prove innocence, or to seek a lesser penalty. Unfortunately, that is not the case with all nations across the world.  A visit to the website of Amnesty International is enough to convince one that death penalty which once executed is irreversible, that many innocent people have gone to the gallows for lack of fair trial, and that a number of  nations prescribe death penalty for  crimes such as smuggling of drugs for which other penalties could be given. Now, one cannot expect the draft-makers of Catechism to have  a quintessential summary of all the arguments for and against imposition of death penalty . Naturally, they may have chosen to limit the arguments to a few words viz. ``new understanding."

Comment: I like your answer and reasoning.  What I was concerned about was whether the "new understanding" comes from experiences in Europe and the Americas or the rest of the world.   I've heard pretty horrible stories about the death penalty is imposed by mobs in Malawi.

Comment: Thanks. The Church should, and is keen to learn from the Good Practices adopted across all nations of the world, irrespective of whether Catholics are in minority in the respective nation , or not. But my personal view is that the Church should not blindly support  putting an end to capital punishment, especially in those cases where  dignity of the victim and of her/his family is involved. For instance, the family of a girl who is gang-raped and murdered , would, if given a chance, finish off the culprits. It  is up to the  state to ensure justice to the victim and the family.

Comment: Rev Graham Steins, an Australian Missionary and  two sons were burnt alive in India in 1999 by religious fundamentalists. Trial court awarded death sentence to the leader of the mob, but  higher courts commuted it  to life imprisonment. Mrs. Steins reacted to the final verdict thus: "        Because of forgiveness I hold no bitterness towards the persons who killed my family. Forgiveness brought healing which is needed everywhere from hatred and violence. But forgiveness does not change the consequences for wrong. Forgiveness and the consequences of our wrongdoing should not be mixed up.".

Answer (score 0):

This is the reasoning:

> This conclusion is reached taking into account the new understanding of penal sanctions applied by the modern State, which should be oriented above all to the rehabilitation and social reintegration of the criminal.
>
> -[Letter to the Bishops regarding the new revision of number 2267 of the Catechism of the Catholic Church on the death penalty](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2018/08/02/180802b.html)

The letter goes on to state that prior Church teaching applied in "a social context in which the penal sanctions were understood differently, and had developed in an environment in which it was more difficult to guarantee that the criminal could not repeat his crime."

The CDF is basically claiming that we now know that criminal penalties are for rehabilitation and social reintegration, not for retribution, deterrence, prevention, and the like.  Francis has been using this same sort of reasoning to argue against life sentences.  I am not agreeing with the decision; I am only explaining the phrase.

Comment: Some criminals can not be rehabilitated or can be integrated into society again. History shows this to be the case. How can doing so by what you are claiming on behalf of the CDF:  **”The CDF is basically claiming that we now know that criminal penalties are for rehabilitation and social reintegration”**. This is your interpretation to a complex situation. I have volunteered many years to souls on death row and not all wish to be rehabilitated. Some admittingly say they would kill again if released. How can a blanket meaning be viable in all situations.

Comment: One wonders  if anyone in America or any other part of the world ever thought that  Bin Laden could be caught alive, given a trial, sentenced and reformed. Similar would be the case of bomber of Oklahoma who  of course, was made to stand trial.